# UIActivityViewController doesn't show Facebook icon (iOS 8)

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift, share

I'm using `UIActivityViewController` to share info to `Facebook`. Got interesting thing on `iOS 8.1` and higher.

If I logged in via `Settings` app and at the same time I have installed `Facebook` app in that case I don't get `Facebook` icon visible in the app list in my app.

It works fine on `iOS 7`.

What to do? How to display `Facebook` icon always?

Example:

```
var _arItmes: NSArray? = ["Title", "Text"]
var _controller: UIActivityViewController? = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: _arItmes as [AnyObject]!, applicationActivities: nil)
_controller?.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo]
self.presentViewController(_controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)    
_controller = nil
_arItmes = nil
```

Answer (score 2):

I first saw this when Facebook updated their app on April 24th. Plain text sharing to Facebook isn't working as long as the Facebook app is installed. After you delete it, it's available again.

If you try to share a URL or an image together with the plain text, you will see Facebook as an option but the text field will be blank. The image or URL will attach without a problem.

I posted a sample project that reproduces this problem on github:

https://github.com/djr/UIActivityViewController-Facebook

This is not an answer, but it's pretty clear that the problem is caused by the Facebook app.